# ArcGIS API Python cant create Webmap/map widget using gis.map() or WebMap() for Spyder and Jupyter Notebook. Any solutions?

Tags: arcgis

I got this error every time i executed either gis.map() or WebMap(). I was able to log in and get other layer and map contents just fine. But just not creating new map.

[Steps to reproduce the behavior and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl85R.jpg)

I have tried with both gis.map() and WebMap()

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the working solution I came up with.

On the Environment of Anaconda Navigator:

- Create new environment
- => name: ArcGISAPIPython, Python: 3.9.17
- => This will give you Spyder with <3.10 Python version so it will be compatible with ArcGIS

On Home of Anaconda Navigator:

- Install CMD.exe Prompt, Powershell Prompt, JupyterLab, Jupyter Notebook, Spyder

On ArcGISAPIPython terminal:

- conda install -c esri ArcGIS
- //for some reason after using the conda install command, it only installed 2.0.0 version
- //here is where the timezone error happen
- Solution:pip install arcgis==2.1.0.3

On Home of Anaconda Navigator:

- downgrade spyder:5.3.3 (pip uninstall ipywidgets)
- -> pip install ipywidgets==7.6.0
- //able to show map Jupyter Notebook and Spyder should work at this point

Reference:  https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/issues/1613